# Add constraint to a field of only the first object from a Java List

Tags: java, validation, constraints, notnull

I have a List of objects List. I have a contraint on the fieldname number as @NotNull. I want to apply the same constraint on the fieldname color but I want it to be mandatory only for the first Car object in the List. I am ok if the color field is null or empty in the remaining Car objects. 
What is the best way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't make a single object instance have a @NotNull field and the remaining instances without @NotNull.

One way I can think about approaching this is creating a custom constructor for the object and passing in something for the color for the first instance of the object and assigning it to the necessary field. This way you can force the first instance to have something in the color field without @NotNull.

Changes you could do for this:

- Access the length of the array
- Have a boolean field in the object, true if first
- If first, assign color; if not first construct generic instance of the object